# Is there a way to pass the type of object with function call?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Webservice which returns Data to user either in XML or JSON format. The issue is the response type is different based on the endpoint the user calls.

```
Dim Response As ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP = aTTADDVALSoapHttpBinding.submitAddVal(ATT_ADDR)
Dim tmpobj = New ServiceResponse()
obj = tmpobj.serviceResponse(Response, oType)
Return obj
```

in this case the type is **ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP** but for another end point it could be **ATT_CLLI_RESP**
Currently i have the type hardcoded in my function

```
Public Function serviceResponse(ByVal response As ATT_ADDR_VAL_RESP, ByVal type As String)
```

What i am looking for is to make this function more dynamic and pass the type in. If that's not possible is there a drawback if i just make the type a generic Object ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care to give a different return type? Have your service client handle that and send back a consistent Type of object - nothing outside the client that calls the service should care what the service returns, be it XML or JSON.. If GetUser returns XML and GetAddress returns JSON, then have a function that calls GetUser and returns a User after deserializing the response XML. Have a function GetAddress that returns an Address after getting the address JSON and deserializing it to an Address

```
Class ServiceClient

  Function GetUser(id as integer) As User
    Return User.FromXml(webservice.GetUserXmlString(id))
  End Function

  Function GetAddress(id as integer) As Address
    Return Address.FromJson(webservice.GetAddressJsonString(id))
  End Function

End Class
```